# Swift- Can't hide or unhide GameScene elements from touchNode input

Tags: swift, updating

I am making my first game and am running into an issue. I have a pause button in my game and when it's pressed I want my "pauseMenu" to unhide, but it's not working. Here's code from my GameScene:

```
if touchNode == pauseButton {
                pauseGame()
}



func pauseGame() {
        self.view?.isPaused = true
        print("Before isHidden is set to false:  \(pauseMenu?.isHidden)")
        pauseMenu?.isHidden = false
        print("After isHidden is set to false:  \(pauseMenu?.isHidden)")
}
```

Here's what prints:

```
Before isHidden is set to false:  Optional(true)
After isHidden is set to false:  Optional(false)
```

As you can see, the pauseGame() function gets called successfully, and the view pauses, but the pauseMenu stays hidden. It's weird because it successfully unhides if I call pauseMenu?.isHidden = false elsewhere, like in my function that is called when the game ends:

```
func gameOver() {
    ...
    toggleViews()
}



func toggleViews() {
        ...
        print("Before isHidden is set to false:  \(pauseMenu?.isHidden)")
        pauseMenu?.isHidden = false
        print("After isHidden is set to false:  \(pauseMenu?.isHidden)")
}
```

This successfuly unhides the pauseMenu and prints the same code:

```
Before isHidden is set to false:  Optional(true)
After isHidden is set to false:  Optional(false)
```

I think the problem has something to do with not being able to hide or unhide something from a touchNode, if I call toggleViews() like this, nothing happens to the gameScene.

```
if touchNode == pauseButton {
                toggleViews()
}
```

I'm at a loss here, I've been trying to fix this for a few hours. Any help is greatly appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Your pausing the view so I think you have to run the `pauseMenu?.isHidden = false`
 before pausing the view.

Comment: I've tried that, same thing happens as it does when I run it after pausing the view.